# Magento 1.9 : Change Password Form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

Currently, change password form is on the same page as account edit information, is there any way to separate change password to different page.

I'm new to Magento & don't know, how to create a custom page can be made in Magento.

Answer (score 4):

I might be late in answering but this will surely help at least others.
Magento has an existing separate file for change password. We are going to use that. The file path is:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/changepassword.phtml

It is not defined in any of the layout files so firstly we will have to mention it in a layout file. I mentioned it in `local.xml`
Since I wanted to use it in `customer/account/edit` page only but the change password form to be separate from the edit account form I mentioned it under `customer_account_edit`. You can change the layout handle according to your preference.

In your theme's `local.xml` file add:

```
<customer_account_edit>
 <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
  <block type="customer/form_edit" name="customer_edit" template="customer/form/edit.phtml">
          <block type="core/template" name="change_password" template="customer/form/changepassword.phtml"/>
  </block>
  </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

In your `customer/form/edit.phtml` just add this line after the form tag closes:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('change_password'); ?>
```

In your `changepassword.phtml` file add the form key inside your `<form>` by adding this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Also, add a hidden field in changepassword.phtml file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="change_password" id="change_password" value="1" />
```

And you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

First check how to create  custom page.Please study [here](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)

=> **Step1: First of all create module control file Module name as  `Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/`**

Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**=> Step2: For create custom route then you need to create config.xml at `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of routers 
    -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>custommodule.xml</file>
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**=> Step 3: Create Controller file where you have show password change form and post action **

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    }
     public function _getModel($path, $arguments = array())
    {
        return Mage::getModel($path, $arguments);
    }


    public function editPostAction()
    {

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
            $customer = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer();

            /** @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $customerForm = $this->_getModel('customer/form');
            $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_edit')
                ->setEntity($customer);

            $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());

            $errors = array();
            $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
            if ($customerErrors !== true) {
                $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
            } else {
                $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
                $errors = array();

                // If password change was requested then add it to common validation scheme
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_password')) {
                    $currPass   = $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password');
                    $newPass    = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
                    $confPass   = $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

                    $oldPass = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer()->getPasswordHash();
                    if ( $this->_getHelper('core/string')->strpos($oldPass, ':')) {
                        list($_salt, $salt) = explode(':', $oldPass);
                    } else {
                        $salt = false;
                    }

                    if ($customer->hashPassword($currPass, $salt) == $oldPass) {
                        if (strlen($newPass)) {
                            /**
                             * Set entered password and its confirmation - they
                             * will be validated later to match each other and be of right length
                             */
                            $customer->setPassword($newPass);
                            $customer->setConfirmation($confPass);
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = $this->__('New password field cannot be empty.');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = $this->__('Invalid current password');
                    }
                }

                // Validate account and compose list of errors if any
                $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
                if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $customerErrors);
                }
            }

            if (!empty($errors)) {
                $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                foreach ($errors as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                }
                $this->_redirect('custommodule');
                return $this;
            }

            try {
                $customer->setConfirmation(null);
                $customer->save();
                $this->_getSession()->setCustomer($customer)
                    ->addSuccess($this->__('The account information has been saved.'));

                $this->_redirect('custommodule');
                return;
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                    ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            }
        }

        $this->_redirect('custommodule');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the helo Amit, how to access this via URL?

Comment: Hi! And how to define custommodule.xml to show the password change form?

Comment: I've tried it like this as well:

    class Web3d_ChangePassword_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{  
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/account_dashboard')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Account'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }